# Use exitserver within a PostScript procedure

Tags: postscript

I want to run code for permanent changes within a PostScript procedure.
Without wrapping it into a procedure, things work fine:

```
serverdict begin 0 exitserver
(PERMANENT_STUFF_HERE) ==
```

However, when wrapping this into a PostScript procedure and calling it with `myprocedure`, it seems the code after exitserver is not executed anymore:

```
/myprocedure {
    serverdict begin 0 exitserver
    (PERMANENT_STUFF_HERE) ==
} def
myprocedure
```

Why is this? I though PostScript procedures were simple macros, just replacing the procedure name with its content when called. Is there any possibility to invoke exitserver/startjob code from within a procedure?

Answer (score 1):

When you run exitserver you terminate the server loop. Immediately. If you were in a loop :

```
{
  (before exit\n) print
  exit
  (after exit\n) print 
} loop
```

Then you would see that the 'before' was processed, but not the after. exitserver is essentially the same kind of operation. Any executing context is terminated, stacks are cleaned up, etc.

So if you do this halfway through a procedure (which is an executable array, and no they are not macros) the execution stack is cleaned up and control returned to the calling context.

Now, when you terminate the job server loop the interpreter carries on processing input, which is why this does what you expect when you aren't in a procedure. The server loop is terminated when you execute the exitserver, the interpreter carries on interpreting bytes fom the input.

You can certainly run 'exitserver' from a procedure, but you can't expect the procedure to continue executing afterwards.

Execution of exitserver is usually frowned upon anyway, you should have a good reason why you want to run it in the course of a PostScript program.

Comment: I've been thinking about this further and now I'm not so sure. How is it possible that "the interpreter carries on processing input" if the exec stack has been purged? The processing of input must be via an inner read loop, or an executable file on the exec stack. So `exitserver` must be more surgical than just clearing the execstack.

Comment: The interpreter carries on processing teh input stream. Anything its in the middle of processing gets dumped, of course. Any new input, following the exitserver, is processed normally. Essentially this returns the interpreter to a 'clean' state and terminates teh job server loop. Input following the exitserver has a 'permanent' effect. You are turning off job encapsulation by doing this. Note that **extremely** old versions of Ghostscript didn't execute a job server loop.....

Comment: Agreed, but the actual effect upon the execstack must be to grab the file object at least, before clearing down to the jobserver loop and starting a new loop to read the salvaged file, scheduling a restart of the jobserver after the file terminates.. It just seems that it's not inconceivable to design `exitserver` to trim the jobserver off of the bottom and leave the user portion undisturbed. Seducing users into nonportable features seems like a big downside to this approach. (I should confess that half of this intellectual exercise was toward the goal of implementing this, not OP's Q.)

Comment: I remember you mentioning that Peter needed to be convinced that a jobserver was necessary. And presumably from the fact that we're still talking about it, it was a hard sell. It is very nice for experimenting that gs runs multiple files *unencapsulated* by default, allowing composition of programs on the commandline. But it's not the normal document-processing usage. I haven't written a line of DSC in 20 years! That's what `ps2write` is for.

Answer (score 0):

As Ken says, `exitserver` isn't going to be usable in a *procedure*. It'll have to be main-line code executing from a stream. But you may be able to use a re-usable null-decoded filtered file. Check the Oct 2006 issue of the [Acumen Journal](http://www.acumentraining.com/acumenjournal.html) for how to make one of those. The example there uses it for image data. But you can put code in it too, and then `cvx exec` it.